# Laravel 5.8 check record in the database if exists not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got a schedules table and i want it to have any duplicates. If the user puts same datas in the form that has already in the database it will not go to `dd('exists')` does anyone know what seems to be the problem?

Here is my update

```
$schedule = Schedule::findOrFail($id);

$validate = Schedule::where('subject_code_id',$request->subject)
                    ->where('teacher_id',$request->teacher)
                    ->where('room_id',$request->room)
                    ->where('start_time',$request->start_time)
                    ->where('end_time',$request->end_time)
                    ->where('school_year',$request->schoolyr)
                    ->where('day',$request->days)
                    ->where('term',$request->term)
                    ->where('semester',$request->sem)
                    ->count();

if($validate == 1){
          dd('exist');
} else{
            $schedule->update($request->all());
}
```

tried 
`dd($request->all());`
I got

```
array:11 [
  "id" => 9
  "term" => "2"
  "semester" => "2"
  "start_time" => "10:30 PM"
  "end_time" => "12:30 AM"
  "scid" => 10
  "teacher_id" => 5
  "room_id" => 6
  "subject_code_id" => 9
  "day" => "SAT"
  "school_year" => "2020"
]
```

Comment: try to dd($validate) to see what you are getting. Then you can check that with the database

Comment: You can do that with validation unique rule, but in your aproach, i think what you need is just `if($validate){...`. Just note that in the way you are doing the query, you will get count > 1 if all fields match with the request inputs. Maybe you want to use orWhere intead where

Comment: but i just want my table to prevent duplicate value in all fields sir @porloscerrosΨ.

Comment: Could you plz add your schedules table schema and the dump of ($request->all());

Comment: Ah, ok. The just use `if($validate) {
          dd('exist');
} else {
       // there are not any record with that data
}`

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI i can see the daa if i `dd($request->all();`

Comment: You Request data should be wrong. that why not matched with data from db

Comment: yes that what is i used in my code in the question @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Well, in the question i see `if($validate == 1){`. And i sugest `if($validate){`, so if `->count()` returns 0, will be false, else will be true. Are you sure you have a duplicated record in DB to test the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the count method to determine if any records exist that match your query's constraints, you may use the `exists` and `doesntExist` methods:

```
$schedule = Schedule::findOrFail($id);

$validate = Schedule::where('subject_code_id',$request->subject)
                ->where('teacher_id',$request->teacher)
                ->where('room_id',$request->room)
                ->where('start_time',$request->start_time)
                ->where('end_time',$request->end_time)
                ->where('school_year',$request->schoolyr)
                ->where('day',$request->days)
                ->where('term',$request->term)
                ->where('semester',$request->sem)
                ->exists();

if($validate){
      dd('exist');
} else{
        $schedule->update($request->all());
}
```

Please visit to see details - [aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates)

Comment: it will not go to the `dd('exist');` instead it will go directly to the `else` statement

Comment: Please check if your data really exists or not...You are using too many conditions, perhaps you are missing something.

Comment: i just want to check if all the request provided is already exist on the db sir. thats whati want

Comment: Yes, this answer meets your requirements. If all of the `$request` values meet exactly with the record you will find the record exists and if one of your condition does not match then it will be a new record.

Comment: why is not going to `dd('exist');` instead it will update

Comment: @Vince because there is not any record in your DB wich match all the clisures. please, show us the request values and wich record in your DB have all this values

Comment: my form has autofill with the current data in it. but if i dont do nothing and press update. it will not go to `dd(exist)` instead it will update the same records

Comment: okay.. I think your requested data did not meet condition - Please check with `count()` . I mean` $validate = Schedule...............->count()` and `dd($validate);` see if it gives you greater than 0 or not. Please type manually before submit form instead of autofill form filler

Comment: if i change to count() and i dd(validate) i get zero @RashedHasan

Comment: That means record does not exist in the database

Comment: seems i got problem in the form names i think i got it.

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do that with laravel unique validation by using Rule class as below

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'subject_code_id' => [
        Rule::unique('schedules')->where(function ($query) use($request) {
            return $query->where('teacher_id', $request->teacher); //you can add all conditions here
        }),
    ],
]);
```

for more see [unique validation rules here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

use `first()` method instead of `count()`

```
$schedule = Schedule::findOrFail($id);

$validate = Schedule::where('subject_code_id',$request->subject)
                    ->where('teacher_id',$request->teacher)
                    ->where('room_id',$request->room)
                    ->where('start_time',$request->start_time)
                    ->where('end_time',$request->end_time)
                    ->where('school_year',$request->schoolyr)
                    ->where('day',$request->days)
                    ->where('term',$request->term)
                    ->where('semester',$request->sem)
                    ->first();

if($validate){
          dd('exist');
} else{
            $schedule->update($request->all());
}
```

Comment: i get null when i dd ($validate) sir. after the first();

Comment: @Vince if recond not exists then it say null otherwise return object